# Angular JS Promise - Binding inside a forEach loop

Tags: arrays, angularjs, binding, iteration, promise

I am using `angular.forEach` to iterate over an array and for each value in the array, I am using a GET/ to retrieve it's name (array contains key), then push that name into another array. This new array is being used in a dropdown box (ngOptions).

The issue I am having is that the drop down is being created before the GET/ responses have arrived, so it just displays blank options, then when they arrive it displays all options in each drop down.

I have the following code:

```
angular.forEach($scope.pots, function(value, key)   {
    $scope.selections = [];
    angular.forEach(value, function(val, ky) {
        if (ky === "selections") {
            angular.forEach(val, function(v, k) {
                $http.get('/selections/' + v).then(function(response) {
                    var response = response.data;
                    $scope.selection = response[0];
                    $scope.selectionName = $scope.selection.name;
                    $scope.selections.push({name : $scope.selectionName});
                    value["selectionNames"] = $scope.selections;
                })

            })
        }
    })
value["selectionNames"] = $scope.selections;
console.log(value);
```

So I am iterating over a list of pots which contains a list of selections, using the GET/ to get a list of names based on the list of selections and finally pushing that into the pot's scope. I am resetting the selection after each pot.

What's causing the issue is that reponses all come at once, and they bypass the `$scope.selections = [];` code, so it just pushes into each pot the complete array from all three pots.

Any tips/advice please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So looks like I've fixed it... Can someone confirm that this is good practice please? I'm basically recreating `$scope.selections` each time I iterate based on the selectionNames value in the pot (value).

```
angular.forEach($scope.pots, function(value, key)   {
    $scope.selections = [];
    angular.forEach(value, function(val, ky) {
        if (ky === "selections") {
            angular.forEach(val, function(v, k) {
                $http.get('/selections/' + v).then(function(response) {
                    $scope.selections = [];
                    var response = response.data;
                    $scope.selection = response[0];
                    $scope.selectionName = $scope.selection.name;
                    var currentSelections = value.selectionNames;
                    angular.forEach(currentSelections, function(csV, csK) {
                        $scope.selections.push(csv);
                    })
                    $scope.selections.push({name : $scope.selectionName});
                    value["selectionNames"] = $scope.selections;
                })

            })
        }
    })
value["selectionNames"] = $scope.selections;
console.log(value);
```